# Select from two tables by adding a field with certain value on certain condition

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table1: Students
ID              Name        EternalToken
200901212       Joe         xxxxxx
200809922       David       yyyyyy
201009122       Chris       zzzzzz

Table2: Banned
ID      StudentID
1       200901212
```

I want to select **all** the students and display an additional field that indicated the student has been banned by hiding the EternalToken

```
SELECT * FROM Students s 
LEFT JOIN Banned b
ON s.ID = b.StudentID
```

This will display both the tables combined. However, I want the result to be like this:

```
ID              Name        EternalToken    Banned
200901212       Joe         NULL            1
200809922       David       yyyyyy          0
201009122       Chris       zzzzzz          0
```

Only students that have been banned, should have an `EternalToken = NULL`

Please note that this is an example of what I am trying to achieve and not exactly what I am doing. 
Students and Banned are just an example, I know that this is not a many to many relationship so I can make it in just one table. But answering this question technically will help me a lot achieving a flexible solution.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you need a simple `IF` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Comment: Did you try `SELECT s.ID, s.Name, CASE WHEN b.Banned = 1 THEN NULL ELSE s.ExternalToken END AS ExternalToken, b.Banned FROM ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following query:

```
SELECT
    s.ID,
    s.Name,
    CASE WHEN b.StudentID IS NOT NULL THEN NULL ELSE s.EternalToken END AS EternalToken,
    CASE WHEN b.StudentID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Banned
FROM Students s
LEFT JOIN Banned b
    ON s.ID = b.StudentID;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that this is sort of the opposite of what the `COALESCE` function does.  `COALESCE` examines a value and returns an alternate should that value be `NULL`.  The above `CASE` expression for the token checks if a value is *not* `NULL`, and returns `NULL` in that case, otherwise revealing the eternal token value.

Comment: Thank you very much Tim! This answers perfectly my question!

Answer (score 0):

Use `case` and `exists`:

```
SELECT s.*,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM banned b WHERE s.ID = b.StudentID)
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) as is_banned
FROM Students s ;
```

In MySQL, you can actually simplify this to:

```
SELECT s.*,
       ( EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM banned b WHERE s.ID = b.StudentID) ) as is_banned
FROM Students s ;
```

I prefer `EXISTS` to the `LEFT JOIN` approach because the logic makes it clear that no rows are going to be added.  A `LEFT JOIN` would multiply the number of rows when there are duplicates in `banned`.

Comment: what about setting EternalToken to null when student is banned?